# Main method error in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
class PrintMsg
{
  public static  void main(String a[])
  {
    System.out.print("\n THE IS MAIN BLOCK");
  }
}
```

the above code compiled successfully but I cannot execute it in the JVM. This 
Error occurred:

> Main method not found in class PrintMsg.Main, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

What do I need to change to fix the error?

Answer (score 8):

This code is valid. But to invoke it, you must execute

```
java PrintMsg
```

and not

```
java PrintMsg.Main
```

as it seems you're doing. `java` expects the fully qualified name (package + class) of a class containing a main method. Your class name is PrintMsg.

Answer (score 1):

yes , It will compile but never execute,as per java specifications the trigger point will starts from main method if it exists in the file

and there is also saying that you need to have public class to start its trigger

try this

```
public class PrintMsg {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        System.out.print("\n THE IS MAIN BLOCK");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compile a java class use `javac classname.java`
for run program use `java classname`

and also make class as public

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must be in your local setup. The code seems ok , and executes fien for me:

run:

THE IS MAIN BLOCKBUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Are you sure you are starting the program correct ?